# How to implement Invoke-SilentlyAndReturnExitCode as a Powershell module function?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, module, scope

Please, observe:

**The method**

```
PS C:\> (Get-Command Invoke-SilentlyAndReturnExitCode).ScriptBlock
param([scriptblock]$Command, $Folder)

    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
    Push-Location $Folder
    try
    {
        & $Command > $null 2>&1
        $LASTEXITCODE
    }
    catch
    {
        -1
    }
    finally
    {
        Pop-Location
    }

PS C:\>
```

**The command to silence**

```
PS C:\> $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
PS C:\> $Command = { cmd /c dir xo-xo-xo }
PS C:\> & $Command > $null 2>&1
cmd : File Not Found
At line:1 char:14
+ $Command = { cmd /c dir xo-xo-xo }
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (File Not Found:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PS C:\>
```

**As you can see, it fails with an exception. But we can silence it easily, right?**

```
PS C:\> $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
PS C:\> & $Command > $null 2>&1
PS C:\> $LASTEXITCODE
1
PS C:\>
```

**All is good. Now my function does the same, so let us try it:**

```
PS C:\> $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
PS C:\> Invoke-SilentlyAndReturnExitCode $Command
-1
PS C:\>
```

Yikes! It returns -1, not 1.

The problem appears to be that setting `$ErrorActionPreference` inside the function does not actually propagate to the command scope. Indeed, let me add some output:

```
PS C:\> (Get-Command Invoke-SilentlyAndReturnExitCode).ScriptBlock
param([scriptblock]$Command, $Folder)

    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
    Push-Location $Folder
    try
    {
        Write-Host $ErrorActionPreference
        & $Command > $null 2>&1
        $LASTEXITCODE
    }
    catch
    {
        -1
    }
    finally
    {
        Pop-Location
    }

PS C:\> $Command = { Write-Host $ErrorActionPreference ; cmd /c dir xo-xo-xo }
PS C:\> Invoke-SilentlyAndReturnExitCode $Command
Continue
Stop
-1
PS C:\>
```

So, the problem is really around `$ErrorActionPreference` - why does it not propagate? Powershell uses dynamic scoping, so the command definition should not capture its value, but use the one from the function. So, what is going on? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Because your `Invoke-SilentlyAndReturnExitCode` function is defined in a *module*, you *must recreate your script block in the scope of that module* for it to see the module-local `$ErrorActionPreference` value of `Continue`:

```
# Use an in-memory module to demonstrate the behavior.
$null = New-Module {
    Function Invoke-SilentlyAndReturnExitCode {
    param([scriptblock] $Command, $Folder)

      $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
      Push-Location $Folder
      try
      {
          Write-Host $ErrorActionPreference # local value

          # *Recreate the script block in the scope of this module*,
          # which makes it see the module's variables.
          $Command = [scriptblock]::Create($Command.ToString())

          # Invoke the recreated script block, suppressing all output.
          & $Command  *>$null

          # Output the exit code.
          $LASTEXITCODE
      }
      catch
      {
          -1
      }
      finally
      {
          Pop-Location
      }
    }
}

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$Command = { Out-Host -InputObject $ErrorActionPreference; cmd /c dir xo-xo-xo }
Invoke-SilentlyAndReturnExitCode $Command
```

On Windows, the above now prints the following, as expected:

```
Continue
Continue
1
```

That is, the recreated `$Command` script block saw the function-local `$ErrorActionPreference` value, and the `catch` block was *not* triggered.

**Caveat**:

- This **will only work if the `$Command` script block contains no references to variables in the originating scope** other than variables in the *global* scope.
- The **alternative** to **avoid this limitation** is to **define the function *outside of a module*** (assuming you're also calling it from code that lives outside modules).

---

#### Background Information

The behavior implies that **your `Invoke-SilentlyAndReturnExitCode` function is defined in a *module***, and each module has its own domain of scopes (hierarchy of scopes).

Your `$Command` script block, because it was defined *outside* that module, is bound to the *default* scope domain, and even when executed from inside a module, it continues see the variables from the scope domain *in which it was defined*.

Therefore, `$Command` still sees the `Stop` `$ErrorActionPreference` value, even though *for module-originated code* inside the function it would be `Continue`, due to setting a local copy of `$ErrorActionPreference` inside the module function.

Perhaps surprisingly, it is still the `$ErrorActionPreference` in effect *inside `$Command`* that controls the behavior, not the function-local value.

With a redirection such as `2>$null` for `*>$null` in effect while `Stop` is the effective `$ErrorActionPreference` value, the mere presence of stderr output from an external program - whether it indicates a true error of not - triggers a terminating error and therefore the `catch` branch.

This *particular* behavior - where the explicit intent to *suppress* stderr output triggers an *error* - should be considered a *bug*, and has been reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002).

The *general behavior*, however - a script block executing in the scope in which it was defined - while non-obvious, is *by design*.

---

**Note**: The remainder of this answer is its original form, which contains general background information that, however, does not cover the module aspect discussed above.

---

- `*> $null` can be used to silence all output from a command - no need for suppressing the success output stream (`>`, implied `1>`) and the error output stream (`2>`) separately.
- Generally, `$ErrorActionPreference` has no effect on error output from *external programs* (such as `git`), because *stderr* output from external programs *bypasses* PowerShell's error stream by default.

  - There is on exception, however: setting `$ErrorActionPreference` to `'Stop'` actually makes redirections such as  `2>&1` and `*>$null` throw a terminating error if an external program such as `git` produces any stderr output.
    This unexpected behavior is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002).
  - Otherwise, a call to an external program never triggers a terminating error that a `try` / `catch` statement would handle. Success or failure can only be inferred from the automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable.

Therefore, write your function as follows *if you define (and call) it outside a module*:

```
function Invoke-SilentlyAndReturnExitCode {
  param([scriptblock]$Command, $Folder)

  # Set a local copy of $ErrorActionPreference,
  # which will go out of scope on exiting this function.
  # For *> $null to effectively suppress stderr output from 
  # external programs *without triggering a terminating error*
  # any value other than 'Stop' will do.
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'

  Push-Location $Folder

  try {
    # Invoke the script block and suppress all of its output.
    # Note that if the script block calls an *external program*, the
    # catch handler will never get triggered - unless the external program
    # cannot be found.
    & $Command *> $null
    $LASTEXITCODE
  }
  catch {
    # Output the exit code used by POSIX-like shells such
    # as Bash to signal that an executable could not be found.
    127
  } finally {
    Pop-Location
  }
}
```